# How to fix this error Cannot run program "svn" Error in Java

Tags: java, maven, svn, ctakes

I have problem loading open source application

I have followed these steps

```
Perform a fresh checkout from SVN
1. Start IntelliJ IDEa.

2.In the "Quick Start" menu, select "Check out from Version Control".
This will display a drop-down box.

3.In the drop-down box, select "Subversion". 
This will open a "Checkout from Subversion" dialog.

4.In the "Checkout from Subversion" dialog, click the "+" button in the top left to add a new Repository. 
This will open a "New Repository Location" dialog.

5.In the "New Repository Location" dialog, enter the svn checkout location of cTakes.
Click "Ok". 
This will inspect the repository.

6.Click the "Expand" triangle.
This should display the directory listing of trunk.
Click "Checkout". 

This will open a "Destination Directory" dialog.
Enter a local directory in which to keep trunk (your sandbox).
Click "Ok". This will open a "Checkout Options" dialog. 
The default options ("Head", etc.) are fine for most users.
Click "Ok". 
This will open a "Working Copy Format" dialog.
Select a (version) format and click "Ok". I use version 1.8, but any should be fine. 
This will start the actual checkout and display a progress dialog. The checkout may take a little while.
After the checkout has completed, a new dialog will ask you if you'd like to open the project. Click "No".
```

but when i reach step 5, i enter svn location

and get this error

> Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "C:\Program
> Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3"):
>
> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

[image]

note this is my first time to use Java

How can I load my application and make run successfully?

Comment: @guleryuz  i check this question already, I dont have "Use command-line client" option from Subversion settings. !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From jetbrains official [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/01/2018-1-changes-to-subversion-integration/):

> ... it is now required to use a command-line svn client for integration
>   with Subversion.
>
> In 2018.1 the SVNKit library has been removed from the IntelliJ
>   platform, resulting in the above changes.

also it seems there is no plugin for svn client in marketplace.

so you should install svn command line as suggested [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-subversion-integration.html)

> IntelliJ IDEA comes bundled with the Subversion plugin. Apart from it,
>   you also need to [download](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) and install the command line client on your
>   machine.